# I want to create a application in ionic with multiple page but i am not able to link other pages to a button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to make something like this <[Plunker][1]>

But when i try this exact code in my ionic application i get nothing on the screen.
I have already asked this question couple of time but nobody was able to helped me till now.

If you know some other alternative or some tutorial or link please post it.

## NOTE i am exactly copying my ionic project code into plunker so that you can better understand it but it might not work in plunker.

### Please help me if you can.

```
<[MY Plunker][2]>




  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/H5n7SM?p=preview
  [2]: https://plnkr.co/edit/fJTaer?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="starter">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
   <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-cordova/0.1.27-alpha/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="js/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/secondController.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <ion-pane>
        <ion-content>
            <div id="wrapper" ui-view></div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova', 'ui.router'])

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
  });
})

 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: "",
          templateUrl: "home.html",
          controller: "homeController"            
    })

    .state('second', {
      url: "/second",
          templateUrl: "second.html",
          controller: "secondController"
    })
});
```

home.html

```
<div style="width:100px;height: 50px;background-color: blue">home</div>
<button ui-sref="second">click</button>
```

second.html

```
<div style="width:100px;height: 50px;background-color: green">second</div>
<button ui-sref="index">click</button>
```

homeController.js

```
app.controller('homeController', function($scope,$ionicPlatform,$state) {

});
```

secondController.js

```
app.controller('secondController', function($scope,$ionicPlatform,$state) {

});
```

Comment: raj what should be the directory of home.html and second.html

Comment: you can keep those two pages in the same directory where index.html is there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer